# Анализ поисковых запросов Play Market

Tags: android, google-play, playmarket

Подскажите, существует ли функционал для анализа поисковых запросов для приложения на play market (по аналогии с "Анализом поисковых запросов" для поисковика google)?
Интересует информация о позиции приложения в результатах поиска на play market, для различных поисковых запросов.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

[Appannie](https://www.appannie.com)
Показывают позиции приложения в результатах поиска по странам для 100  ключевых слов бесплатно. Отслеживать можно любое приложение, а не только своё.

При регистрации не используйте почтовый ящик на gmail, он не принимается, так как разработчики сервиса уверены, что у разработчиков приложений обязана быть почта на своём личном домене, а не публичном.